# How do i put values of one column in seaborn point plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, seaborn

i'm graphing a point plot with two columns from a df (`['group', 'preds']`).  I have another column, `ratio` that i would like to use as labels above each point, so the viewer can see how the preds correspond to the ratio.  I haven't found anything in the docs that instructs on how to do that.

See example below.  I just need a line or something that adds ratio as a lable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

group = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
preds = [.57, .64, .66, .68, .70, .71, .72, .75, .77, .86]
ratio = [.06, .07, .1, .23, .56, .66, .77, .88, .89, 1.07]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(group, preds, ratio)), columns = ['group', 'preds', 'ratio'])
df.head()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
title = 'Base Line Data only Lift Chart'

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16,10]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
#ax = plt.figure(facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = sns.pointplot(x ='group', y = 'preds', data = df)
ax = plt.title(title)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ax.text`. Note that my ax refers to `ax=sns.pointplot(...)`, not `ax=plt.title(...)` like you did in your code. I had also included some keyword parameters for you to tweak and explore on your own in `ax.text()`.

Code for plotting

```
plt.style.use("fivethirtyeight")
title = 'Base Line Data only Lift Chart'

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16,10]
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
#ax = plt.figure(facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = sns.pointplot(x ='group', y = 'preds', data = df)

for x,y,z in zip(group,preds,ratio):
#change f'{z:.2f}' to str(z) if you want something simpler
    ax.text(x-1,y+0.01,f'{z:.2f}',horizontalalignment='center',color='m',weight='light')

plt.title(title)
```

Output
[image]